# gitlab-shell: Disallowed command

Tags: git, shell, ssh, gitlab

I've installed the recent version of GitLab on Ubuntu 14.04 and it works fine except pushing to the remote.

Running `ssh git@example.com "git-receive-pack repo.git"` works well. In ~/gitlab-shell/gitlab-shell.log, result is

> INFO -- : gitlab-shell: executing git command git-receive-pack repo.git for user with key key-1.

But when I'm running `git push`, the log says:

> WARN -- : gitlab-shell: Attempt to execute disallowed command git receive-pack 'repo.git' by user with key key-1.

And the output is:

> fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Disa

The output of `ssh git@example.com "git receive-pack repo.git"` is

> "Disallowed command"

So the difference between allowed and disallowed is a missing dash.

My git versions:

- Local git version: 2.2.1 (OS X)
- Remote git version: 1.9.1 (Ubuntu 14.04)

How can I fix that? Is there a config param?

Answer (score 6):

I have been having the same problem, and editing ~/.gitconfig solved the problem.

Something, at some time in the past, had modified my local ~/.gitconfig file and inserted this entry:

```
[remote "origin"]
        receivepack = git receive-pack
```

I modified it to the following, and now everything works well.

```
[remote "origin"]
        receivepack = git-receive-pack
```