# Unable to clone/pull/push a repository with Git for Windows 2.14 over SSH

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I recently formatted my computer and upgraded to Windows 10 but forgot to backup my SSH keys for my gitlab repositories. So I have just created a new SSH key and copypasted it to gitlab.com/profile/keys.

Now I've created a new folder to one of my pre-existing projects but when I try to clone it with

```
git clone git@gitlab.com:user_name/project_name.git
```

I am getting

> GitLab: Disallowed command
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.ssh -v git@gitlab.com

If I try...

```
ssh -v git@gitlab.com
```

Or...

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.com
```

I got to see the correct Welcome message with my name.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try the solutions described there: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/26022

Comment: I did not find anything helpful there. Any more ideas?

Comment: It could be an issue due to a version change in Git. See: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/36028 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29588258/gitlab-shell-disallowed-command
Can you check your .gitconfig?

Comment: I would like to download a previous version of Git to test it out but I don't know how. In older releases I cannot find the installable files.

Comment: Okey, found my way out to download Git-2.13.0 and git clone works as expected. Thank you very much Michael Troger!

Comment: I added the solution as an answer so that you can accept it please! I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:
the bug is already solved in [Git for Windows 2.14.0(2)](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.14.0.windows.2)**

The problem was due to a version conflict between Git and GitLab on Windows. The OP could solve the issue using an older Git version (2.13.0).  [GitLab Issue 36028](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/36028) was a known bug which occured when trying to pull/fetch/clone/push with Git 2.14 via SSH. Quote:

> Git v2.14 onwards uses git upload-pack instead of git-upload-pack, at least over SSH, and GitLab blocks it as a disallowed command.

More maybe helpful links when having problems with GitLab via SSH:

- [gitlab-shell: Disallowed command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29588258/gitlab-shell-disallowed-command)
- [SSH Clone Permission denied (publickey) - All Users & All Repositories](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/26022)

Comment: I can confirm that this issue is resolved in `git version 2.14.0.windows.2`