# unknown git/gitolite command: 'git upload-pack RepoName'

Tags: git, gitolite

We are using gitolite on a server and are connecting via SSH. From one day to another we get the following error:

```
$git pull
FATAL: unknown git/gitolite command: 'git upload-pack 'RepoName''
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Access Rights did not change. Repository exists. Server is up and running.

Git Version: git version 2.14.0.windows.1

Any Idea what might have happened?

Comment: Yes, switch to 2.140.0.windows.2: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45539717/6309

Comment: Thanks! Provide it as an Answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in "[Can't clone on windows but can clone on linux from Gitlab server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45539717/6309)", GitLab or Gitolite  are set to parse for `git-xxx` commands.

But with 2.140.0.windows.1, git send commands as "`git xxx`", which means the command (now in args[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45539717/6309)) was not detected.

See [commit 0f33428](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/commit/0f3342804fc6fa558a7c9e220e7e9ab4c86e8226) which reverses that: you can then use [`git/releases/tag/v2.14.0.windows.2`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.14.0.windows.2).